# Unclear message padding during encryption

Tags: java, encoding

I'm reviewing some code which is supposed to handle encryption and I've found a step that I'm not understanding:

```
StringBuilder encryptedPaddedMessage = new StringBuilder(encryptedMessage.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < encryptedMessage.length; i++) {
        if (((int) encryptedMessage[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            encryptedPaddedMessage.append("0");
        }

        encryptedPaddedMessage.append(Long.toString((int) encryptedMessage[i] & 0xff, 16));
}
```

Can anyone explain what is the purpose of this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds a leading `0` to the hex output of each byte when it's less than `0x10` (and would be a single hex digit).

It could be rewritten:

```
encryptedPaddedMessage.append(String.format("%02x", encryptedMessage[i] & 0xff));
```

Note that it's not really "crypting", rather "encoding" into hex string.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very convoluted way of printing a byte

Comment: @Aurasphere, maybe that's where "encryption" is ;)